# Como sacar aleatorio una matriz con UFT

Tags: java, selenium, visual, vbscript

Soy nuevo en UFT y no conozco mucho el lenguaje visual basic.
Estoy intentando sacar un dato de una matriz aleatoriamente, ahora mismo me lo está sacando pero el problema es que a veces me saca todos o algunos y solo lo quería uno. Os paso mi código, muchas gracias.

```
localidad = Array ("Madrid", "Barcelona", "Ciudad Real") 

for i = RandomNumber(0,3) To ubound(localidad)
     
     print localidad(i)
Next
```

Comment: Saludos. Si lo que quieres es **sacar un datos de una matriz** y que sea aleatorio; no necesitas el `for`, usa tu variable `i` como la tienes en `print localidad(i)` solo que previamente le asignes el valor de la posición de la matriz que deseas obtener (me parece sería `i =  RandomNumber(0,3)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está solucionado, es por la versión de UFT.
Os paso el código si algún día lo necesitáis.
Saludos

```
localidad = Array ("Madrid", "Barcelona", "Ciudad Real") 
Randomize 
for i = lbound(localidad) = 1 To ubound(localidad) = 1
i = RandomNumber(0,2)
print "localidad: " + localidad(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

para sacar sólo un elemento aleatorio has de prescindir del bucle:

```
localidad = Array ("Madrid", "Barcelona", "Ciudad Real") 

int i = RandomNumber(0,3)  
// Imprimimos
print localidad(i)
```

Comment: Con ese valor, siempre me saca el primero de la matriz, necesito hacer un for para que vaya recorriendo la lista y luego decir que me saque uno